# How to include an image in R function documentation using `roxygen2`?

Tags: r, image, roxygen2

I write an R package and I want to include some images in some of the function documentations. For documenting the functions I use `roxygen2`.

Since `roxygen2` handles Markdown very well, I saved the image in the `Rd` directory and tried to include it like this (within a `@param` tag):

```r
![](my_image.png)
```

When I build the function documentation, it looks like this:

[image: image not found]

It seems, as if the inclusion worked in principal, but the image is not found.

I also tried to store the image in `inst/extdata/images/my_image.png` and to include it like this:

```r
![](`r system.file(package = "my_package", "extdata", "images", "my_image.png")`)
```

This did not work either.

So, where do I have to put the images to make them available and how can I include them in the function documentation?

Comment: See section 2.7 of the Writing R Extensions manual.  It's talking about what ends up in the .Rd file; I'm not sure if Roxygen has any special support.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put your image in the folder `man/figures` and type such an Roxygen code:

```
#' \if{html}{Here is my figure:
#'
#'   \out{<div style="text-align: center">}\figure{myfigure.png}{options: style="width:750px;max-width:75\%;"}\out{</div>}
#'
#' }
#' \if{latex}{Here is my figure:
#'
#'   \out{\begin{center}}\figure{myfigure.png}\out{\end{center}}
#'
#' }
```

Comment: Can't you just use the `\figure{}` macro, i.e. simply `#' \figure{myfigure.png}`?

Comment: @user2554330, `\figure{my_figure.png}` works in principle. Then, the image is displayed in its original size.